# List posts grouped by taxonomy and child taxonomies

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following post structure on my dash

```
<ul>
  <li>Tax 1
    <ul>
      <li>Tax 2<br>
        <span>- Post 1</span><br>
        <span>- Post 2</span>
      </li>
      <li>Tax 2
        <ul>
          <li>Tax 3<br>
            <span>- Post 1</span><br>
            <span>- Post 2</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<li>Tax 1
    <ul>
      <li>Tax 2<br>
        <span>- Post 1</span><br>
        <span>- Post 2</span>
      </li>
      <li>Tax 2
        <ul>
          <li>Tax 3<br>
            <span>- Post 1</span><br>
            <span>- Post 2</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to show each post as a child of the last category related to it, I created a scheme but it does not group the sub categories

```
    <?php 
      $member_group_terms = get_terms( 'categoria' );
    ?>

  <?php
    foreach ( $member_group_terms as $member_group_term ) {
        $member_group_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'documento',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'categoria',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array( $member_group_term->slug ),
                    'operator' => 'IN'
                )
            )
        ) );
        ?>
        <h2><?php echo $member_group_term->name; ?></h2>
        <ul>
        <?php
        if ( $member_group_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $member_group_query->have_posts() ) : $member_group_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li><?php echo the_title(); ?></li>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php
        // Reset things, for good measure
        $member_group_query = null;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
  ?>
```

The problem here is that it does not group the subcategories, leaving them listed as if it were the level 1 category.I need it to display as I mentioned above, grouped by sub categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a recursive function. These can be a little hard to wrap your head around sometimes, so hopefully the comments in the code work for you.

In my sample code, the cpt is `staff` and my taxonomy is `staff-type`, you'll need to update appropriately. Also, I actively avoid `setup_postdata` and similar functions, but it is just for personal reasons, feel free to use them if you want.

Here's the two functions:

```php
/**
 * @param WP_Term[] $terms
 * @param int $parentId
 */
function render_terms(array $terms, int $parentId = 0)
{
    // Find all of the parents with this ID
    $parents = array_reduce(
        $terms,
        static function (array $carry, WP_Term $term) use ($parentId) {
            if ($term->parent === $parentId) {
                $carry[] = $term;
            }
            return $carry;
        },
        []
    );

    // If there are no parent items at this level, stop process
    if (!count($parents)) {
        return;
    }

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($parents as $term) {
        echo '<li>';
        //Show the term name
        echo sprintf('<strong>%1$s</strong>', esc_html($term->name));

        // Show the child terms
        render_terms($terms, $term->term_id);

        // Show the child posts
        render_posts($term);
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

function render_posts(WP_Term $term)
{
    $results = get_posts(
        [
            'post_type' => 'staff',
            'tax_query' => [
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'staff-type',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => $term->term_id,
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                    'include_children' => false,
                ]
            ]
        ]
    );

    if (count($results)) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            echo sprintf('<li>%1$s</li>', esc_html($result->post_title));
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

And to use them:

```php
$all_terms = get_terms(
    [
        'taxonomy' => 'staff-type',
    ]
);

render_terms($all_terms);
```

You might have to play with indentation a little to match things. Also, there's a thing called breadth-first and depth-first, and your sample appeared to be the latter where you render the hierarchy as deep as possible, then show the content. This is controlled by these two lines in `render_terms`:

```php
        render_terms($terms, $term->term_id);
        render_posts($term);
```

If you wanted a breadth-first, you'd just swap those two.

Comment: Is there any way the post title can only appear once? For example, I have a category 1, child of category 1 named "Category 2", and I also have category 3, child of category 2.

I put the post only related to category 3 but it continues showing in the others.

Comment: I updated the code above adding `'include_children' => false` to the post query which should do what you want, I think. I also switched it over to user term ID's as a minor efficiency thing, and also bolded the category title to make it a little more obvious.